# Is it possible to reassign an existing event from one Solspace Calendar to another ?

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

Let's say I have an existing event called "My Event" on a Solspace calendar called "Social".

Is it possible to reassign "My Event" to a different calendar eg: "Sports" - without deleting "My Event" from "Social" & recreating it on "Sport" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This currently isn't built into Calendar, but if your calendars use the same fields, you should be able to manually adjust the `calendarID` column in the `craft_calendar_events` database table. Otherwise, you'll have to delete the event and create it again for the correct calendar.

Sometime in the future we plan on seeing if we can add the option to allow changing of calendars. The issue for us is that each calendar is able to have a different field layout and tabs, etc, so it complicates things. :)